# How to check whether a particular process starts running and when it stops

Tags: linux, unix

I need to develop a shell script which will shoot an email as soon as a particular unix process starts running and will shoot a mail as soon as the process is completed/stopped. Can you please help me with how can I do this checking? I can check whether a process is running or not, but here I need to check whether the process starts running and when it gets completed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modify it's execution.

Comment: Wrap the program in a `mail ; program; mail` script.

Answer (score -1):

```
while [ -z $(pidof UnixProcess) ]
do
   sleep 1
done

//send email programs running

while [ $(pidof UnixProcess) ]
do
   sleep 1
done

//send email program completed
```

This might not be the most efficient, be what you wanted, and might not even work. But it is the first that springs to mind when reading your question.

As long as there isn't any process with your name running we just wait, when it is we leave the first while loop and send the email. Then repeat the process, as long as the program is running we wait, and when it is no longer running we send an email.